# Python function for have a new array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I have a question. I have two lists: a=["a","b","c","d","e","f"] and I have 6 values in another list: b=["1.1", "1.2", "1,3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6"] and I want to obtain a dataframe like this:

```
 a   b   c   d   e   f
1.1 1.2 1.3
1.1 1.2 1.3
1.1 1.2 1.3
    1.2 1.3 1.4
    1.2 1.3 1.4
    1.2 1.3 1.4
        1.3 1.4 1.5
        1.3 1.4 1.5
        1.3 1.4 1.5
            1.4 1.5 1.6
            1.4 1.5 1.6
            1.4 1.5 1.6
```

I hope you can help me with this (I tried different ways but I have no idea how to do it)

Comment: _"I tried different ways"_: What have you tried? Show us so that we can comment on them.

Comment: Can you explain the ruling behind the output?

Comment: Hello, guys. No worries, Mike67 answered this question. Thanks for trying anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a basic loop to create a list of lists then create a dataframe from the main list.

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

a=["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
b=["1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6"]

cnt = 3
lst = []
for x in range(len(b)-cnt+1):  # shift across columns
    for y in range(cnt):  # three duplicate rows
       lst.append(['']*x + b[x:x+cnt] + ['']*(len(b)-x-cnt))  # single row
       
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=a) 

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
  a    b    c    d    e    f
 1.1  1.2  1.3
 1.1  1.2  1.3
 1.1  1.2  1.3
      1.2  1.3  1.4
      1.2  1.3  1.4
      1.2  1.3  1.4
           1.3  1.4  1.5
           1.3  1.4  1.5
           1.3  1.4  1.5
                1.4  1.5  1.6
                1.4  1.5  1.6
                1.4  1.5  1.6
```

Comment: question. What if i have N values in b and I want to do the same. Like arrays 3xN instead 3x3 like the previous example

Comment: It should still work if `a` and `b` are the same length.

Comment: what if b has a length two times "a" always?

Comment: You need to determine how you want to see. `a` is the column header list. What should the other columns have as headers?

Comment: Hi Mike. Basically I am trying to change the order in the data frame. instead, have those 1.1 values in a column I would like to have then as rows. I am trying to do that because those values are Levenstein's values to see how similar is my sequence to a database. In that case, for example, the sequence "ABC" is not too similar to another sequence that I have in my database (that is why I should have 1.1 below A, B, and C) and so on with the other values. The values of this example are made up, by the way. In general, my "sequence" is ABCDEF and my scores are inside the list b.